# Non-representable irreducible matroid of rank at least 5?

Tags: matroid-theory

Can anyone tell me an example of a matroid of rank 5 or higher which is not a product of two lower rank matroids and is not the independence matroid of a finite set of vectors in a vector space over any field?

Comment: Any irreducible matroid of rank 5 or higher that contains the Vamos matroid (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vámos_matroid) as a minor will do.